# Change default Posts page

Tags: posts, wp-admin, admin

In my Admin Panel, I am constantly checking my Posts by state and visitor count via the All Posts link on the lefthand menu bar. My desired URL looks like:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&orderby=post_views&order=desc
```

But the default for this link is just

```
wp-admin/edit.php
```

How can I make it so that the default link for my Posts is like the first one?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in a previous question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434373/in-wordpress-how-do-i-set-the-default-admin-sort-order-for-a-custom-post-type-t#answer-31520570

This accepted answer will walk you through how to set up the pre_get_posts callback. That would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your child theme's `function.php`:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_244328_post_menu' );
function wpse_244328_post_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][2] = 'edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&orderby=post_views&order=desc';
}
```

This will change the default value for the *Posts* menu from:

```
edit.php
```

to

```
edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=post&orderby=post_views&order=desc
```

Comment: I love this answer except that when I implement it, it makes my Posts submenu stop working. Is there a way to implement this but still have the submenu appear?

Comment: Updated the code, submenu will be still be available now.